# Tableau, send parameter to query

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

i work with text table in tableau and i want to be able to click on a cell in the table, so that the value of the cell would be transfered\sent to sql query or procedure, does anyone know if this is possible?
if not, is there a way i could define a column in a text table as a parameter with multiple values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you use a custom sql option. once you connect to your DB/DS select custom sql and then pass your variable through tableau parameter.

Comment: but how can i pass my variable throw parameter dynamically? i want when i click on cell it's pass the value to procedure or custom sql, i don't want to select the value from parameter, i want to select him from table! so , how can i do that? thanks a lot